# How can I redirect where the Django admin page takes you when you log in?

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, admin

What happens right now:

1)  User goes to PROJECT_URL/admin/login/ and is presented with the usual form to enter username and password.
2)  Enters both and clicks "Log In".
3)  Successfully logs in, but doesn't go anywhere, staying at PROJECT_URL/admin/login, which is replaced with this error:

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    PROJECT_URL/admin/login/

The requested admin page does not exist.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

If the user manually deletes the login/ part of the address in the address bar and hits enter to go there, they can successfully access the admin just fine.

I keep hitting a brick wall trying to look up workarounds.  All I need is for the login page, on a successful login, to go to the URL I tell it to go to, but I can't find any way to do this.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Django's admin site login works without redirects. Admin site just hooks on every request started with "/admin/", and if the user is not authorized - shows login form on the same url. I.e. if you want to give access to the admin itself - just point users on "/admin/", without "login/". If you want to use login form for your project - [write an appropriate view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests) or [use one provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).